# Windows7 boot manager - how to add Ubuntu to Windows boot menu?

Tags: windows-7

I had to rid of grub2 and go back to default Windows7 booting method because with grub2 Windows updates were always failing (reverting after about 90% completion). Now  without grub2 windows updates are working properly and I'd like to ask you if I can still somehow boot my Ubuntu partition, now using Windows boot manager? Is there any configuration file where such bootlist can be configured? Under advanced system settings in OS startup options I can only see Windows 7 as default OS system. How to add Ubuntu there?

I have only 1 disk with partitions. In "dispart" utility, I see partition #2 which is my Windows7 and logical parition #3 where Ubuntu is installed on.

There is MBR used.

Comment: Although this is not the place for software recommendations, before UEFI became standard I used the free version of [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) with success. With UEFI its options became limited, and I don't know if you can add Linux to a UEFI boot. All of which said, I've not had problems updating Windows 10 with Grub as boot manager by making it [remember the last OS booted](https://askubuntu.com/a/149572/479613).

Answer (score 0):

try to run `msconfig` from command line.

Then go to the second tab...
I have no information about how to change the specific changes in this tab.

Edit: Follow the instructions in this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader